# MySQL - If It Starts With A Number Or Special Character

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT * 
FROM `thread` 
WHERE forumid NOT IN (1,2,3) AND IF( LEFT( title, 1) = '#', 1, 0)
ORDER BY title ASC
```

I have this query which will select something if it starts with a #. What I want to do is if # is given as a value it will look for numbers and special characters. Or anything that is not a normal letter.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to select all the rows whose "title" does not begin with a letter, use REGEXP:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM thread 
   WHERE forumid NOT IN (1,2,3)
     AND title NOT REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]'
ORDER BY title ASC
```

- **NOT** means "not" (obviously ;))
- **^** means "starts with"
- **[[:alpha:]]** means "alphabetic characters only"

Find more about [REGEXP in MySQL's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/regexp.html).

Comment: working url to regexp manual is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 1):

it's POSSIBLE you can try to cast it as a char:

```
CAST('#' AS CHAR)
```

but i don't know if this will work for the octothorpe (aka pound symbol :) ) because that's the symbol for starting a comment in MySQL

Comment: Im a real MySQL newbie. That NOT IN clause is waayy over my head just to put it into context.

Could you explain a little more please :)

Comment: just replace `AND IF( LEFT( title, 1) = '#', 1, 0)` with `AND IF( LEFT( title, 1) = CAST('#' AS CHAR), 1, 0)`, but like i said, i don't know if it will work w/octothorpes

Comment: ah, so... sorry, thought i'd give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM `thread` t
   WHERE t.forumid NOT IN (1,2,3) 
     AND INSTR(t.title, '#') = 0
ORDER BY t.title
```

Use the [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) to get the position of a given string - if you want when a string starts, check for 0 (possibly 1 - the documentation doesn't state if it's zero or one based).