# remove a character from beginning of a field value in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have about 2000 records in a MySql table. a specific field in some of them starts with colon character (:) that is not needed. I have to remove this character from the beginning of it.

How can I do that ? Should I use regular expression ?

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the first character using `SUBSTR` function. Like

```
UPDATE tableName SET field = SUBSTR(field, 2) WHERE field LIKE ':%';
```

or you can use `regex` also, to match beginning character (`^`) of the word. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214035/mysql-if-it-starts-with-a-number-or-special-character#answer-1214271) for how to use `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = REPLACE(columnName, ':', '')
WHERE columnName LIKE ':%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfd60/1)

Comment: This isn't right: you'd be removing **all** ':'s, including those in mid-field.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET FIELD = SUBST(FIELD,1)
WHERE LEFT(FIELD,1) = ':'
```

Comment: the ':%' might match too much and REPLACE replaces ALL occurrances