# MySQL if first character is number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an mysql script to see if the first character is a number or not, this is what I go so far

```
select CASE WHEN user_id REGEXP '[0-9]+' then 1 else 0 end as user_id  from table
```

it returns all my data as 1...the colum is a varchar, I will have user_id like this `1234` or this `USER-484` or `ADMIN-464567' IS what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you try to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: FYI - `CASE` returns the result of the first true condition - e.g. `CASE WHEN [logical condition] THEN X ELSE Y END`, returns the X or Y but nothing from the [logical condition] area

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447048, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511945, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214035

Answer (score 2):

Try this to check if starting letter/digit is a number:

```
select CASE WHEN user_id
REGEXP '^[0-9]+' 
then 1 else 0 end as user_id
from table;
```

or

```
select CASE WHEN user_id
REGEXP '^\d+' 
then 1 else 0 end as user_id
from table;
```

I am just wondering about your query arrangement. I thought it should be like this,

```
select user_id
from table
where REGEXP '^\d+' ;
```

But yours is actually working with the correct `regex`. :)

### * [SQLFIDDEL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/589dc/3)

Comment: @user1269625 +1 for the question, coz I haven't used earlier the way you have used the `regex function`. And it seems to work :) with the correct `regex` given.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to display the user_id instead? Then put your regexp in the `WHERE` clause

```
select user_id from table
where
user_id REGEXP '^[0-9]+'
```

Also you're missing a `^` which means "at the beginning of the line"

Answer (score 0):

Since you are missing ^ before [0-9] it matches numbers at any place in your field. By specifying ^[0-9] it means that it should BEGIN with a number. So try using '^[0-9]'