# How to make an regexp request with TYPO3 queryBuilder

Tags: mysql, regex, typo3, query-builder, typo3-10.x

I currently have a big list of entries in my TYPO3 Ext that causes the Site to have pretty poor loading times, so i want to split up the Entry list alphabetically. For that I'm using the queryBuilder to select only those entries, that start either with an a, b, c and so on. But im stuck now when it comes to numbers and special chars. I found this: [MySQL - If It Starts With A Number Or Special Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214035/mysql-if-it-starts-with-a-number-or-special-character) which is exactly what I need. But I have no clue how to make an REGEXP in the queryBuilder. Can someone help?

TYPO3 version is 10.4.6

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although @eliashaeussler and @Jonas gave you solutions which probably works and you should try them in the first step, for performance reasons I'd rather suggest adding a separate, indexed and hidden column in your table that stores first char and search by it. It will be always MUCH faster than searching with `LIKE` or `REGEXP`. Of course, you'll need to add some work to update that column after each insert or update of your record. If you are interested in that solution, leave a comment and I'll explain to you how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this works for you:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable($tableName);
$result = $queryBuilder->select('*')
    ->from($tableName)
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->comparison(
            $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier($fieldName),
            'NOT REGEXP',
            $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('^[[:alpha:]]')
        )
    )
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();
```

This creates a query like this (assuming `$tableName = 'foo'` and `$fieldName = 'baz'`):

```sql
SELECT `foo`.*
FROM `foo`
WHERE `foo`.`baz` NOT REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]'
```

Reference: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/10.4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Expression/ExpressionBuilder.php#L97-L100

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I wanted every special char and number, not every letter. So i just added NOT before your REDEXP and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `LIKE` to find strings starting with a given character.

### Using LIKE

```
$firstCharacter = 'A';

$q = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
       ->getQueryBuilderForTable('mytable');
$q->select('field')
  ->from('mytable')
  ->where(
    $q->expr()->orX(
      $q->expr()->like(
        'field',
        $q->quote(strtolower($firstCharacter) . '%')
      ),
      $q->expr()->like(
        'field',
        $q->quote(strtoupper($firstCharacter) . '%')
      );
```

upper/lower case could be left out of course if the DBMS is case insensitive.

### Using REGEXP

@eliashaeussler gave a good example for that.

While `LIKE` is supported by Doctrine dbal, `REGEXP` is not. You would lose cross-DBMS compatiblity. This is probably fine if you target a specific site but should not be used in public [extensions](https://extensions.typo3.org/) of course.